# Unable to locate where PHP requires extension?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, lamp

After

```
php -v
```

I get some warnings about broken PHP extensions.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/raphf.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/raphf.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/raphf.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/raphf.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/propro.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/propro.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I want to remove this requires from config, to fix issues, but I can't find from where it required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick an easy way is

```
 php -i | grep ini
```

That should spit out all the modules ini files that are loaded. You can then edit the ini file and comment the extension= line which should disable it on the next restart

Comment: Thanks. But it's possible the extensions is precompiled, and not included in configs?

Comment: it should give you paths to look in to see where things are loaded from

Comment: like `Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d`